# Subdivision of a cube

Tags: mesh, modifiers

[image]

[image]

I am unable to get the subdivision like in the first photo. When I subdivide the cube I end up with a shape in the second image but when I select the face, I am unable to select individual faces like in the first photo. Am I missing something?

My question is then: How do I select the faces like in the first photo?
Second Image is what I have and First Image is what I would like.
Thankyou

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to apply the modifier if you want to be able to select these faces. For the moment, as long as the *Subdivision Surface* modifier is not applied, these faces are virtual.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Feels good to have help!